# Cannot display image on listview using simple cursor adapter

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter, custom-lists

I had populated a listview using simplecursoradapter. However, I want to add images, wherein if the answer is correct it should display check on the right and if null or incorrect it should display an x-mark. It does not display anything but there is no error. Here is my activity code:

```
public class Results extends ListActivity{
DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
private Cursor mCursor;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.resultslist);

    db.open();
    fillData();
    db.close();

}
private void fillData() {

    mCursor = db.getAllInfo();
    startManagingCursor(mCursor);
    String[] from = new String[]{DBAdapter.KEY_QUESTIONS, DBAdapter.KEY_CORRECTANSWERS, DBAdapter.KEY_YOURANSWERS}; 
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textViewquestionresults, R.id.textViewcorrectansresults, R.id.textViewyouranswerresults};

    SimpleCursorAdapter c=
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.rowresults, mCursor, from, to);


        setListAdapter(c);

}
private class c extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

        Context lcontext;


    public c(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        lcontext = context;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int pos, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    v = super.getView(pos, v, parent);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewresults);
    final TextView tvQuestion = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
    final TextView tvCorrectAns = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewcorrectansresults);
    final TextView tvYourAns = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewyouranswerresults);
     if(tvYourAns.equals(tvCorrectAns)){
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.greencheckmark);
    }else{
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.redxmark);
    }
    return v;

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When extending SimpleCursorAdapter, you shouldn't override `getView()`.

You should override `newView()` and `bindView()` instead.

In `newView()` inflate your layout and initialize your views.

In `bindView()` set your views' values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll try it tomorrow since I do not know how to use these methods... I'll make some more research tomorrow. thanks